# What is git revert --quit for?

Tags: git

From the `git-revert(1)` manpage it is not clear to me what the exact differences between the `quit` and `abort` options of the `revert` command are.

From my exercises with the `revert` command I made the observation that the `abort` option works very similar to the one of the `rebase` command in that it tries to reconstruct the pre-operational state of the current branch.

Also what are the practical use cases of the `quit` option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> From my exercises with the `revert` command I made the observation that the `abort` option works very similar to the one of the `rebase` command in that it tries to reconstruct the pre-operational state of the current branch.

You're on the right track:

- `git revert --abort` rolls the sequencer state back, so the workspace and history end up as they were before the start of `git revert`;
- `git revert --quit` only removes the sequencer state, so the workspace and history remain as they are (with a partial `revert` in progress but forgotten about).

From my quick experimentation, if a revert needs manual intervention, `git revert --quit` only forgets the previous commits; `REVERT_HEAD` remains in place so you still need to `--continue` or `--abort`. The latter keeps the forgotten commits as a result of the `--quit`.

As far as use cases go, I've never needed to use `--quit`, but I'd imagine if you're part-way through a `revert` and decide you're not going to need the remaining reverts, but you do want to keep those you've committed so far, then it might come in handy...